# Query for remaining balance

Tags: sql, sqlite

Query for remaining balance

I am using SQLITE 3.1.1

The scenario is the ff:
Let us say Total Quantity is 11.

[image]

The formula should be:

**Total Quantity - Quantity Used = Remaining**

It should look like this:

- First: 11 - 1 = 10
- Second: 10- 6 = 4
- Third: 4 - 0 = 4
  and so on..

Expected Result:

[image]

Also, Remaining value can't be lower than 0.

I currently have this SQL query but it doesn't get the **Remaining** query result for the next transaction but rather it always starts with **Total Quantity**.

```
SELECT
    filter_maintenance.maintenance_id,
    filter_maintenance.stock_id, 
    filter_maintenance.quantity_used,
    filter_maintenance.date_registered,
    filter_maintenance.date_changed,
    inventories.stock_name,
    SUM(inventories_order.order_quantity) - filter_maintenance.quantity_used AS Remaining
FROM filter_maintenance
INNER JOIN inventories ON filter_maintenance.stock_id = inventories.stock_id
INNER JOIN inventories_order ON filter_maintenance.stock_id = inventories_order.stock_id
GROUP BY filter_maintenance.maintenance_id
```

This is the output I currently have:

[image]

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok, I will ask again: how do you order the rows with the same `Stock ID`? Why row with `quantity used` = 0 is not first?

Comment: hi @RadimBača, thanks for getting back. Had to repost. Experienced some problems. I'ts ordered in my database according to datetime. quantity used = 0 is the latest transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using sqllite and there are no window functions you need to use a self-join instead. I assume `maintenance_id` is a primary key in `filter_maintenance`.

```
SELECT
    filter_maintenance.maintenance_id,
    filter_maintenance.stock_id, 
    filter_maintenance.quantity_used,
    filter_maintenance.date_registered,
    filter_maintenance.date_changed,
    inventories.stock_name,
    sum(inventories_order.order_quantity) - filter_maintenance.sum_quantity_used AS Remaining
FROM 
(
    SELECT  fm1.*,
            sum(fm2.quantity_used) AS sum_quantity_used 
    FROM filter_maintenance fm1
    INNER JOIN filter_maintenance fm2 ON fm1.stock_id = fm2.stock_id and
                                         fm1.date_registered >= fm2.date_registered
    GROUP BY fm1.maintenance_id
) filter_maintenance
INNER JOIN inventories ON filter_maintenance.stock_id = inventories.stock_id
INNER JOIN inventories_order ON filter_maintenance.stock_id = inventories_order.stock_id
GROUP BY filter_maintenance.maintenance_id
```

Comment: Correct. maintenance_id is a primary key in filter_maintenance. @Radim, when you say fm, fm1 and fm2 do you mean filter_maintenance?

Comment: I edited the result that worked for me using your code. I just tweaked it a tiny bit. Thank you Radim! You saved my day! Btw, where would I add the part that remaining balance shouldn't be lower than 0?

Comment: @roger note that the `date_registered` is not mentioned in the whole question, therefore, you probably did not ask quite clearly. And you are welcome :)

Comment: At the time I posted the question I didn't think it was necessary until you asked me in the comment section. I will edit it now.